# J2ME Find Group name and numbers

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet

i want to find **group name and related phone no** for my **sms application**

i know how to find phone book contact name and numbers
but i want to find group name and number.
is it possible with j2me???

Answer (score 1):

See this link for your reference.

[PIM API...](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/pim/pim5/)

You need to get the categories and get the contacts based on your category.

And see this link for how to send the SMS.

[Send SMS...](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/select-contact-from-phonebook-and-send.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have idea about how to send sms and hot to read contact but don't know how to find group name and related phone numbers

Comment: see the PIM api link. Its having how to get category(group) and contact numbers.